# Cannot log in to Drupal site

Tags: drupal-7

I have a VM that I set up to do development on two sites hosted on Acquia with the same codebase.  I'm using version Drupal 7.26.  I have it where I can access both sites from the host computer, but when I try to log in using `/user/login` on either site, I get nothing.  The POST returns a 404 containing the log in page again.

I've tried settings `$cookie_domain = '.my-site.dev'` as well as `$cookie = 'www.mysite.dev'`.  Neither has any effect.  I also tried adding a bunch of random charactersto the file to make sure I was editing the correct file; with the random characters, pages didn't load at all.  (See https://www.drupal.org/node/611920#comment-3110010.)

I also tried doing `repair table sessions`.  I forgot which site I saw that recommendation from.  I also tried `delete from sessions` just for kicks.  Neither worked.

Any ideas?  Thanks!

*edit*: Per https://www.drupal.org/node/261411#comment-3182566, I tried to go to www.mysite.dev/?q=user/login.  This did not give me a 404, but I had tried (unsuccessfully, it seems) to reset my password through the database.  I'm at least getting an error about a bad username/password combination rather than nothing at all.  Still, I would think /user/login should have worked, too.

*edit 2*: The production site uses CAS, but logging in through /user/login still works.

Comment: what happens if you try to go to /?q=user

Comment: Thanks @cport1.  I get a 200 with the login page.  When I try to log in, a get 200 from the POST request, but my username and password don't work, and I get the appropriate error message.  This is a pretty fresh backup from production, certainly from after I last changed my password.

Comment: And I'm doing this in a new private browsing window in Firefox.

Comment: I forgot to mention in my original question that the production site uses CAS, so the CAS module is installed.  I noticed this because when I go to the site, I get a whole bunch of cookies from different places, including our CAS server.

Comment: Can you use drush on this instance? drush user-password USERNAME --password="SOMEPASSWORD"

If not, you could update it like this: https://www.drupal.org/node/1023428

Comment: `Sorry, there have been more than 5 failed login attempts for this account. It is temporarily blocked. Try again later or request a new password.`  That's pretty funny.  `delete from flood` and it worked.

Comment: cool, so you got it to work?

Comment: Only with the `/?q=user/login`.  `/user/login` still gets me a 404.  I wouldn't say that it's working, but I have a workaround and can continue with what I was doing until I get this working.  Thank you for your help so far.

Comment: That should be in admin/config/search/clean-urls ... However, you may have modules such as html purifier affecting this as well. Glad you can login though, cheers.

Comment: I hope you atleast applied the security patches from 7.32&7.34 on your sites...

Comment: @cport1, I currently have that turned on, but it's still not working.  I also get AJAX errors when I try to use the administrative overlays, e.g., `An AJAX HTTP error occurred.  HTTP Result Code: 404 Debugging information follows Path: /admin/structure/views/my_view/preview/default/ajax`  @Pinoniq, once I have my development environment working, that's very high on my list of things to do.

Comment: Ah, here's the rest of it: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5758551/1102726.  I needed to enable mod_rewrite by executing `a2enmod rewrite`.  Is that the answer?  I guess so.